# PHP MYSQL LIKE for match multiple word in description

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a ajax search function using PHP. It's working correctly but have little problem with filtered results,

I have product description like below

```
POWER CORD C13-C14 SVT 250V 10AMP GREEN JACKET 8 FEET
```

but when user search for  **power cord green** there is no result showing. i think this because of those above words are not in same order.

**here is my SQL code - $qr is user search word**

```
SELECT 
      product_name,product_desc
      FROM j25_virtuemart_products,j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb
      WHERE         
       j25_virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id =j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id 
       AND j25_virtuemart_products.published=1 
       AND (product_name LIKE '%$qr' OR product_desc LIKE '%$qr
```

when user search for **power cord green** i need to get **POWER CORD C13-C14 SVT 250V 10AMP GREEN JACKET 8 FEET** as a suggestion. can anyone tell me how to write query for get those kind of result. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use FULL TEXT searching. Before using it make sure to check your database engine if it support FULL Text. Also you have to index fields like title, description whatever you have to support full text.

YOu can refer to

- http://tips4php.net/2010/03/create-your-own-fulltext-searchengine-with-php-and-mysql/
- http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Also note that:

- Mysql is deprecated avoid using it, go for `mysqli` or `PDO`
- Use parameterized queries

Comment: working nicely.. thanks a lot for this
SELECT 
   product_name,product_desc
   FROM j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb
   WHERE  MATCH (product_desc, product_name) AGAINST('".$qr."')

Answer (score 5):

The LIKE operator will not help you here. You'll need to look into [FULLTEXT searching](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/). If you're unwilling to use MyISAM (it does have its [drawbacks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-locking.html)), you could look into alternatives such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: @SunethKalhara See the link I added to my post. That should get you started. Although you should use the PDO or MySQLi extensions instead of the default mysql functions used in the examples.